# Handle audio play completion callback in dialogflow (Media responses)

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm handling an intent by playing a `MediaObject`. I want to create an intent handler that will catch the callback of media play completion, the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#media_responses) shows an example on how to write fulfillment code to handle it.

> **Building your fulfillment**
>
> The code snippet below shows how you might write the fulfillment code
>   for your Action. If you're using Dialogflow, replace
>   actions.intent.MEDIA_STATUS with the action name specified in the
>   intent which receives the actions_intent_MEDIA_STATUS event, (for
>   example, "media.status.update“).

I am confused with the part of the dialogflow instructions. The intent that I handle and return a MediaObject is called `smoothie-02` and I have a fallback for it which what gets handled after the media finishes being played, but I want to create another intent and handle it there instead. What I want to do is to create a new intent that would handle it, instead of it going to the fallback intent of `smoothie-02` intent.

`smoothie-02` handler

```
app.dialogFlow.intent('smoothie-02', (conv) => {
    const welcomeContext = getConvContext(conv, AppContexts.WELCOME);

    givenName = welcomeContext.parameters['given-name'];
    fruitTypes = welcomeContext.parameters['FruitTypes'];

    if (!conv.surface.capabilities.has('actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO')) {
        conv.ask('Sorry, this device does not support audio playback.');
        return;
    }

    conv.contexts.set("actions_capability_media_response_audio", 5);

    // Zoe says something
    let response = `Ooh good choice ${givenName} ! `;
    response += fruitTypes.length > 1 ? `${fruitTypes[0]} and ${fruitTypes[1]}` : `${fruitTypes[0]} `;
    response += `${drinkType} ` ;
    response +=  'coming right up. But will you first turn me on?';
    console.log(response);

    conv.ask(response);

    conv.ask(new Suggestions("Don't be shy"));

    // Blender plays
    conv.ask(new MediaObject({
        name: 'Blender Sound',
        url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/zoe-mortimer.appspot.com/blender.wav',
    }));
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I needed to do is create a new intent and add `actions_intent_MEDIA_STATUS` in the Events, and that will be the intent that would handle the media playback finished callback. Credits to [this article](https://www.eisbahn.jp/yoichiro/2018/06/media_responses_en.html)!

[image: media status event]